# ASP.Net Angular 6 HttpClient cookie only sent if url path is the same

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I have a Webservice with ASP.Net Web Api 2 and an Angular 6 client.
Now on my server in my controller I add a auth cookie with:

```
   [RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
   public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage LogInUser(LoginData loginData)
       {
          // .. check password ...
          FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
               1,                                     // ticket version
               loginData.UserName,                         // authenticated username
               DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
               DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),           // expiryDate
               true,                                 // true to persist across browser sessions
               String.Empty,                          // can be used to store additional user data !!! Cannot be null!!!
               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie

            // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            CookieHeaderValue cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            HttpResponseMessage respMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            respMessage.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie});
            return respMessage;
        }

    }
```

On server side cors are enabled and on client side I always set 'withCredentials' :

```
@Injectable()
export class IcaHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });
    console.log("outgoing request", request);
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

so if I do a post with a HttpClient to 'localhost/api/auth' I get the cookie in the response header, the next post to another method in 'api/auth' the cookie is sent also, but now when I send the request to another path e.g. 'api/users' the cookie is not sent..
The question is why?

Comment: Make sure what both services for `api/auth` and `api/users` injected in the same module where interceptor provided.

Comment: do you have example code?

Comment: Sorry, an example of what code? Can you provide your example, how you make calls, how you declare service, which doing request with such api.

Comment: Nothing special. A normal httpclient Post or Get without anything else. Only the mentioned interceptor that always inserts the withcredentials.

Comment: I have a single Module where all services use the same interceptor. Withcredentials is also always true,

Comment: If intercepter defined in Module A, all requests should be from services or component defined in module A. If component or service which call `api/auth` defined or provided in Module A, but component or service which call `api/users` will be defined or provided in component B your intercepter will work only for module A.

Comment: Updatedmy comment above

Comment: @Andreq after reading a few times your first response  I     know what you wanted to explain to me and will try to implement it the way it is explained here https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8. Tomorrow I will report. But I am not 100% sure why the cookie is only saved for thesl service that requested it for first time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long testing I have looked in the browser what information is in the cookie.
Although I set the path to null at server the path is set to 'api/auth'.
In the server I now set the cookie path explicit to '/':

```
[RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
   public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage LogInUser(LoginData loginData)
       {
          // .. check password ...
          FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
               1,                                     // ticket version
               loginData.UserName,                         // authenticated username
               DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
               DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),           // expiryDate
               true,                                 // true to persist across browser sessions
               String.Empty,                          // can be used to store additional user data !!! Cannot be null!!!
               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie

            // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            CookieHeaderValue cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            // This is the important part!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            cookie.Path = "/";
            HttpResponseMessage respMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            respMessage.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie});
            return respMessage;
        }

    }
```